# Angular 8 - Routing not happend - Mat table row

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I don't know why my routing is not happened after clicking row. 
No error is showing.
Path is changing in URL from "http://localhost:4200/vendor-list" to "http://localhost:4200/vendor-list/vendor"
But the page is not changing.

> vendorlist.component.html

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="ordersDisplayedColumns"></tr>
<tr (click)="displayData(row)" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ordersDisplayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

> vendorlist.component.ts

```
displayData(row)
  {
    console.log(row);
    this.router.navigate(["/vendor-list/vendor/"]);
  }
```

> myrouting.module.ts

```
{path:'vendor-list',component:VendorlistComponent,
children:[
  {path:'vendor',component:VendorComponent, 
]},
```

Comment: I think one of your colleague already asked this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61029475/5429428

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to route after clicking row of mat table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61027230/how-to-route-after-clicking-row-of-mat-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{path:'vendor-list',
 children:[
   {path:'vendor',component:VendorListComponent,canActivate:[AuthguardGuard]},
   {path:'vendor',component:VendorComponent,canActivate:[AuthguardGuard]}

 ]}
```

check this one please

Answer (score 0):

Route to a unique ID for each row using url parameters.

> vendorlist.component.html

```
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="ordersDisplayedColumns"></tr>
<tr (click)="displayData(row, i)" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; let index as i; columns: ordersDisplayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

> vendorlist.component.ts

```
displayData(row, id)
  {
    console.log(row);
    this.router.navigate([`/vendor-list/vendor/${id}`]);
  }
```

> myrouting.module.ts

```
    {path:'vendor-list',component:VendorlistComponent,
children:[
  {path:'vendor/:id',component:VendorComponent, 
]},
```

Comment: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'matRowDefAs' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. ("ow *matHeaderRowDef="ordersDisplayedColumns"></tr>

Comment: Check your imports in the module in context. Have you imported MatTable Module?