# How to route after clicking row of mat table

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, angular-routing

I am not able to route after clicking row of mat table. It not showing any error. In URL path is changing properly like this from "http://localhost:4200/vendor-list" to "http://localhost:4200/vendor-list/vendor". But the same page(table) is showing. Below i am attaching my code, can anybody help if i did something wrong in this

> vendorlist.component.html

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="ordersDisplayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr (click)="displayData(row)" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ordersDisplayedColumns;"></tr>
```

> vendorlist.component.ts

```
export class VendorlistComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router:Router) { }

  displayData(row)
  {
    console.log(row);
    this.router.navigate(["/vendor-list/vendor/"]);
  }
}
```

> myroute.module.ts

```
{path:'vendor-list',component:VendorlistComponent,canActivate:[AuthguardGuard],
children:[
  {path:'vendor',component:VendorComponent,canActivate:[AuthguardGuard]

]}
```

For testing,I placed  selector before my table. then the page was showing but below my page, the same table of previous page was also showing

Comment: @GouravGarg myroute.module.ts is my routing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change routing as below:

```
{path:'vendor-list',
 children:[
   {path:'vendor',component:VendorListComponent,canActivate:[AuthguardGuard]},
   {path:'vendor',component:VendorComponent,canActivate:[AuthguardGuard]}

 ]}
```

If you want to change complete content you need to add parent component in children array as '' path.

If you want to use some content from parent component then you have to use router-outlet and your config is good for that.